# Spark driver application mapping (Cluster mode)

Tags: apache-spark

Is there a way to find a driver to application mapping in cluster mode??

I understand, on submitting an application the `CreateSubmissionResponse` would return the driver-Id which could be used to monitor or kill the driver program.  I am trying to see if there is any alternate way of doing it without storing the driver id.

I saw Driver UI `http://<driver>:4040` which gives the application information under  Environment section, but spark documentation mentions

> *"If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc)."*

This makes it difficult to map which driver runs on which `port`.

So is there a way to get all driver id and their applications.

***Environment:*** Spark standalone with Zookeeper as Cluster manager.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If you have Spark history server up and running, the simplest way is to
>   use its REST API
>   http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api. Check
>   /applications endpoint